# Microwave links

Tags: waves, experimental-physics, earth

If the record for microwave links is 235km long, and the microwave waves must travel in a straight line (and cannot go through solids such as the sea or objects in between), then how did they account for the curvature of the Earth? 235km should have too much curvature to see the receiver pole. The scenario is explained in 10:17 in this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZcrSyMM1ZM&t=705s

Answer (score 2):

A lot of the long distance links are over bodies of water eg the [Red Sea](http://www.singerexecutivedevelopment.com/the-worlds-longest-microwave-radio-link/).

The [refractive index of air](https://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-r/rec/p/R-REC-P.453-8-200102-S!!PDF-E.pdf) is slightly greater than one and decreases with height.

Due to the vertical change in refractive index the microwaves undergo refraction.

[image]

So the path of the microwaves is not along a straight line.

[image].

The images came from [Point-to-Point Radio Link Engineering](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Luigi_Moreno/publication/273439447_Point-to-Point_Radio_Link_Engineering/links/58f779024585152e2782e0d6/Point-to-Point-Radio-Link-Engineering.pdf?origin=publication_detail).